# ListContourPlot axis label

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to have the correct labelling of axes in a ListContourPlot that I create via

```
testTable=Table[x + y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];

Show[ListContourPlot[testTable,DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}},FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]
However, I want to have the correct labelling: i.e. 0<x<5 and -5<y<5. How can I do this?

Update:

However, this cannot be correct as e.g. for x->3, y->4 : x+y=-1 !

Comment: `testTable = Table[x + y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];

Show[ListContourPlot[testTable, DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]`

Comment: This does not make it correct? Please see my update.

Comment: `testTable = Table[x + y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
ListContourPlot[Thread@testTable, DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 1):

Your question's title refers to "axis label" which probably caused many to focus on the `FrameTicks`. However, I suspect your question actually has to do with the `Contours`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

testTable = Table[x + y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
```

If you do not like the default [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) you must specify your own.

```
yTicks = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
       Join[
    Table[{y, ToString[y], {0.012, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
               AbsoluteThickness[0.4]}}, {y, -5, 5}], 
    Table[{y, "", {0.009, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
               AbsoluteThickness[0.3]}}, {y, -5, 5, 1/2}]], 
   First];
```

If you are not adding options to an existing graphic or combining graphics there is no need for [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

**EDIT:** From the documentation, "ListContourPlot[array] arranges successive rows of array up the page, and successive columns across." Consequently, your data should be transposed.

```
ListContourPlot[Transpose@testTable,
 DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yTicks, yTicks /. _String :> ""}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ListContourPlot[testTable,
 DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][-5, 5, {10, 5}], Automatic}, 
      {Automatic, Automatic}},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

In general, you can use `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"] `` as

```
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][min, max, {maxnumberofmajorticks, maxnumberofminorticks}]
```